# how to overload constructors with a generic trio?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, overloading

I need to create two constructors, the first should take in three items as parameters. The second constructor takes in a single item and the Trio will then consist of three of these items.

I guess I am having trouble wrapping my head around overloading constructors while using this().

I get an error saying "cannot reference Trio.item1 before supertype constructor has been called"

```
public class Trio<T> {

  //instance data variables
  private T item1, item2, item3;

  /**
   * this a constructor for all three items
   * @param item1
   * @param item2
   * @param item3
   */
  public Trio(T item1, T item2, T item3) {
    this.item1 = item1;
    this.item2 = item2;
    this.item3 = item3;
  }

  /**
   * This second constructor takes in a single item
   * and then the trio will consist of three of these items
   * @param itemGroup
   */
  public Trio(T itemGroup) {
    this(item1, item2, item3);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second constructor, I'm pretty sure you were supposed to pass a `Trio<T>` (not just a `T`). Like,

```
/**
 * This second constructor takes in a single item
 * and then the trio will consist of three of these items
 * @param itemGroup
 */
public Trio(Trio<T> itemGroup) {
    this(itemGroup.item1, itemGroup.item2, itemGroup.item3);
}
```

As is, you have not assigned anything to `item1`, `item2` or `item3` (which is why you can't use them). The other possibility would be

```
public Trio(T item) {
    this(item, item, item);
}
```